# 'glGetTexLevelParameter' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

Alright, so before anyone asks, yes I do have `<gl/gl.h>` included. Anyone have any idea why this one function, `glGetTexLevelParameter`, isn't showing up?

Answer (score 5):

Because that's only the base name of the function.  You need either the integer array or float array form, as in `glGetTexLevelParameteriv` or `glGetTexLevelParameterfv`.

See [this link](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetTexLevelParameter.xml) for details.

Comment: That worked. thank you. I'll accept this answer as soon as I can.